# Is it possible to test tweepy function module with pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, tweepy

I'm using tweepy for an application using Twitter. In order to check if my code do what it is expected to do, I want to test it. But here the thing, tweepy module,at the end, consists of API requests. For example, I want to test this following `is_already_liked` function:

```
class twitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
            API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
        )
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)

    def is_already_liked(self, tweet_id: int) -> bool:
        """Checks if the tweet is already liked

        Args:
            tweet_id (int): id of the tweet

        Returns:
            bool: True if the tweet is already liked else False
        """
        return self.api.get_status(tweet_id).favorited
```

I would like to test it on a fake tweet_id that I would create. Is there a way to do something like that with pytest and some mocking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

*In test_script.py*

```py
# module.submodule.script: where you define or import twitter
from module.submodule.script import twitter

class Tweet:
    def __init__(self, favorited):
        self.favorited = favorited


def test_is_already_liked(mocker):
    api = mocker.patch("drafts.temp.tweepy.API")
    api.return_value.get_status.side_effect = (
        lambda x: Tweet(True) if x == "123456" else Tweet(False)
    )
    t = twitter()
    assert t.is_already_liked("123456")
    assert not t.is_already_liked("654321")
```

```bash
pytest .\tests\test_script.py
# Output: 1 passed
```

Comment: That works. Is it possible to make it tweet_id specific ? Like `api.return_value.get_status.("123456").return_value.favorited = True`

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. Cheers.